# Adding text-shadow on scroll

Tags: scroll, blur, css

I would like to know if there is a way to blur dynamically text with text-shadow css3.

Basically, when I scroll down, I'm adding slowly shadow, and when I scroll up, I remove slowly text-shadow.

Here's what I have for now

```
   var nombreBlur = "5";
   $('.contenantNoir').css({ 'text-shadow' : '0px 0px '+nombreBlur+'px #fff' });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've done :

```
$(".contenantNoir").css({'text-shadow': '0px 0px '+(( e.currentTarget.scrollY - 630) / 18)+'px #FFffFF'})
```

You can find the code from this website : http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/1072/JQuery-Text-Hover-Blur-effect-